# Передача коллекции абстрактных типов из C# в Java в формате Json

Tags: java, c#, json

Допустим, нужно передать по сети из C# в Java класс :

```
public class Message
{
    public List<Event> Events;
}
```

Где `Event` - это абстрактный класс => в коллекции хранятся ивенты разных типов.

Вопрос в том, как Java может восстановить это все в свои эквиваленты классов на своей стороне?

Или "восстанавливать" придется вручную добавив в абстрактный Event поле с enum'ом, по которому Java уже будет у себя сопоставлять его со своим эквивалентным классом?

Comment: Любой JSON сериализатор (по крайней мере в C#) позволяет при сериализации устанавливать дополнительную информацию, в то числе тип (обычно это `$type`), вот на его основе и делайте нужные преобразования на стороне "клиента".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а это разве не будет работать только в том случае, если мы юзаем одну и туже либу с типами? Как мне кажется это не будет работать для JAVA и нужно енум какой-то заводить

Comment: Я не сказал, что это будет работать из коробки. Вам так или иначе нужен будет "конвертер", свой маппер, который преобразует одно в другое. Мой комментарий был больше про "поле с enum'ом". А так, имхо, делать абстракции в строго структурированном типе данных, это бред, особенно, если это некое API или что-то подобное. Лучше создать свойства "Event A", "Event B" и т.д. и их уже заполнять, а еще лучше, разделить это на разные отправляемые "пакеты.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance#bd-2-per-class-annotations

Comment: @kami, в данном случае скорее преобразования при помощи `jsonschema2pojo`: [Generate a Java Class From JSON](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generate-class-from-json).  Код классов может генерироваться как непосредственно по JSON-данным, так и по заданной схеме JSON Schema, в которой описана структура таких данных, см. [json-schema.org: Creating your first schema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step)

Comment: @NowhereMan ну не знаю. Я вопрос понял как "что бы такого передать в json, чтобы в java всё забралось без проблем по разным наследникам". Про "чем бы сгенерировать pojo" не увидел, не думаю что ТС это требуется. Скорее всего - разрабатывается API, где в язык передатчика С#, а приемник целенаправленно предполагается на Java. Вот и рассматривается "получится ли у приемника"

Comment: Да, можно и так понять..